# Whats the shortest way to definitely rewrite "loose equality logic" to "strict equality logic" ie: `==` to `===`?

Tags: javascript

I have lots of JavaScript legacy code where I want to rewrite all loose equalities to use strict equalities ie. `==` vs `===`. But I often have no idea what value is stored by the compared variable.

Without knowing what the values are, is there a way to rewrite something like this to use strict equality that holds true for all cases?

```
        if (transformedValue != value) {
          ...
        }
```

What I have so far is (probably incorrect)

```
if (
  transformedValue !== value && 
  ('' + transformedValue) !== ('' + value) &&
  !transformedValue !== !value
)
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use find/replace in your editor??

Comment: @silencedogood in think OP means "find all the things that will break when you do the regex replace" but the question isn't very clear.

Comment: @JaredSmith Ohh I see thx.

Comment: If you are not sure what value you have stored in those, then there is no real good way to replace the loose equals. You might be currently getting `undefined == null` in one place and it works but using strict equals, it wouldn't.

Comment: why would you want to do that? maybe some function casting everything to the type of the thing on the left, checking the `typeof value`?

Comment: Why do you want to reinvent the loose equals without using loose equals? Sure, loose equality is not exactly precise in a lot of situations but it's actually clearly defined. Re-implementing it seems like a waste of time that will result in code that is worse to look at and might even include bugs.

Comment: loose inequalities still have their place in the language.  `== !== ===`. If your legacy code still have their intended use then there isn't any good reason to replace them except you just want to do it for fun ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no automated way of rewriting all of the `==` in your code to `===` so that it works for every possible case.

You will have to bite the bullet and change them all to `===` and run your unit tests to discover what broke (you do have unit tests, right? Right!?). Or go through them one by one, making sure you understand the potential values so that the correct choice can be made. Or keep them as `==` and deal with the outliers.

It should be noted that the preferred method is the last choice — keep them as is.

Comment: Having been in a similar situation (lots of loose equalities which I foolishly thought I'd "fix"), I can definitely recommend *not* doing that. Changing `==` to `===` introduced a subtle bug in one place where one of the values was sometimes `null` other times `undefined` and so it would fail in only some cases. Even with unit tests that would be very hard to catch unless the code is *extensively* tested beforehand. And from my experience with legacy code, it isn't. A lot, or even all, tests would be newly written and might not exercise all the current values you actually get.

Comment: @VLAZ: TRUTH. :)

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here and agreeing with both @VLAZ and @heretic-monkey.

It might be possible to check types of all the variables and come up with an equality function as mentioned by @flash-thunder , but it is completely impractical. I'm posting my attempt below, It passes every equality listed on on the [Equality comparisons and sameness doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#A_model_for_understanding_equality_comparisons) but it is surly not "definative"

`if ( !looseEquals(transformedValue,value) ) {`

```
function looseEquals(a, b) {
  var typeA = typeof a;
  if (a === null) {
    typeA = 'null';
  }
  if (Array.isArray(a) || a instanceof String) {
    a = '' + a;
  }
  if (Array.isArray(b)) {
    b = '' + b;
  }

  switch (typeA) {
    case 'object':
      return a === b;
    case 'string':
      if (a === '') {
        return b === '' || b === false || b === 0;
      }
      return a === '' + b;
    case 'number':
      if (a === 0) {
        return b === '' || b === false || b === 0;
      }
      return a === Number(b);
    case 'undefined':
    case 'null':
      return b === undefined || b === null;
    case 'boolean':
      if (a) {
        return b === true || b === 1;
      } else {
        return b === false || b === 0 || b === '';
      }
    default:
  }
}

var tests = [
  [undefined, undefined],
  [null, null],
  [true, true],
  [false, false],
  ['foo', 'foo'],
  [0, 0],
  [0, false],
  ['', false],
  ['', 0],
  ['0', 0],
  ['17', 17],
  [[1, 2], '1,2'],
  [new String('foo'), 'foo'],
  [null, undefined],
  [null, false],
  [undefined, false],
  [{ foo: 'bar' }, { foo: 'bar' }],
  [new String('foo'), new String('foo')],
  [0, null],
  [0, NaN],
  ['foo', NaN],
  [NaN, NaN],
];

for (const [a, b] of tests) {
  if (looseEquals(a, b) !== (a == b)) {
    console.log('mismatch!', a, b);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a helper method

`const isEqual = (a,b) => a === b`

and the replace all the occurances with this method call, and that way you can abstract this logic.

Comment: That seems like an interesting solution... I'd prefer not to do that just because of how odd that practice is. It might be best to do what the accepted answer suggests and "bite the bullet" or rely on unit tests.

Comment: I did not downvote your post. Someone else did. I agree with you that it was unwarranted.